# How to limit the login to a single user using flask-login?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am new to Flask app development. Currently, I have an ML app deployed on a Flask server.

Right now, anyone can register and login to run an ML inference. But I want the active user to a single user. That means if any user is active in the deployed site, then no other user can login to the site.

Here is some relevant code:

```
from flask_login import (
    LoginManager,
    UserMixin,
    login_user,
    login_required,
    logout_user,
    current_user,
)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(
        "Username", validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=50)]
    )
    password = PasswordField(
        "Password", validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)]
    )
    remember = BooleanField("Remember me")


@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
                return redirect(url_for("index"))

        return redirect(url_for("error", code="500.3"))

    return render_template("login.html", form=form)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to how I could implement my idea? I am using `Flask-Login` if anyone knows a built-in feature that may help.

Comment: I don't know of any specific features, but you could have a boolean in your `User` model, such as `logged_in`. Then whenever someone logs in, you query all users for the field `logged_in`: if it equals `None` they can log in; else they don't get access. It would be similar to the line where you are checking for a username that matches the one from the `LoginForm()`, but you check for the `logged_in` feature instead.

Comment: Agree @JakeJackson however you would want to make sure that your sign-out logic was bullet-proof to prevent lock out. E.g., if the user never actually clicks the sign-out button.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It's basically a race condition, which has a lot of issues if not properly accommodated.

Answer (score 1):

Try flask-limiter, flask-limiter allows you to set a limit for a page or a IP address

Visit https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/